# Pundit: Ensure current_user is user from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

Apparently, [you can't access the params hash](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/140) in a Pundit policy. It makes sense that they want to expose as little information to the policies as possible. But one use case I'm running into, which I would think would be quite common, is to check that the `current_user` is the user from the params.

So here's my `new` action in my controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id])
    unless current_user.admin? || current_user.id == @user.id
      flash[:alert] = 'Access denied.'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
    @review = @user.reviews.build
  end
  ...
end
```

So here, I'm saying to authorize if the user is an admin, or the current user is the same as the one in the URL. Otherwise, the user with the id of 2 could go to `/users/1/reviews/new`.

There doesn't seem to be any way to handle this in the policy, because I can't pass the `params[:user_id]` into the policy.

Is there a way to handle this authorization scheme from a Pundit policy, rather than handling auth logic in my controller?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question is out of date.

When `pundit` does the authorization in the controller, it will pass two objects. One is `record` and another is `current_user`. But you only need to provide the `record` when you call the `authorize` method, `current_user` will be passed automatically.

`#authorize(record, query = nil) ⇒ true`

In your case, when you call `authorize(@user, :new?)`, in your policy, `@user` will be referenced as `record`, and `current_user` will be referenced as `user`.

Therefore, in your policy:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def new?
    user.admin? || record == user
  end
end
```

And you can check the policy in your controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id])
    authorize(@user, :new?)

    @review = @user.reviews.build
  end
  ...
end
```